# Pass variables args to a map function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
def func(a,b,c=None):
    print (f'a: {a} | b: {b} | c: {c}')

list(map(func, [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 12}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]))
```

> TypeError: func() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'b' and 'c'

Is there a way to do this using the `map` function or do I need to use some other approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass variable arguments using the `*args`:

```
def func(*args):
    print (f'a: {args[0]["a"]} | b: {args[0]["b"]} | c: {args[0].get("c")}')
```

**Output**:

```
a: 1 | b: 2 | c: 12
a: 1 | b: 2 | c: None
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is pass it to a placeholder function that then unpacks the values, for example:

```
def _func(dict_item):
    """
    This will receive the dict_item as a single object,
    It will then pass those unpacked values (which the `map()` function cannot do)
    and pass them to `func()`
    """
    return func(**dict_item)

def func(a,b,c=None):
    print (f'a: {a} | b: {b} | c: {c}')

>>> list(map(_func, [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 12}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]))
a: 1 | b: 2 | c: 12
a: 1 | b: 2 | c: None
```

Also, this would be a good candidate for a decorator, especially if this is a pattern that is being reused a lot. For example:

```
def unpack(func):
    """Given a dict as a single arg, 
       call the function with those kwargs unpacked."""
    def _unpack(dict_obj):
        return func(**dict_obj)
    return _unpack

@unpack
def func(a,b,c=None):
    print (f'a: {a} | b: {b} | c: {c}')

>>> list(map(func, [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 12}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]))
a: 1 | b: 2 | c: 12
a: 1 | b: 2 | c: None
```

Answer (score 0):

For a pythonic approach, I would use a list comprehension.

```
args_list = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 12}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}]
[func(args['a'], args['b'], args.get('c', None)) for args in args_list]
```